# Alterar estilo da navbar com scroll

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Faz um tempo que venho procurando um modo de fazer uma `navbar` do bootstrap 3 ter um comportamento parecido com a navbar do Google+, ao dar scroll para baixo ela fica menor e apresenta no lugar dos menus com ícone e título apenas menus com ícone, ao voltar ao topo ela assume o estilo inicial.

Por exemplo, por padrão minha navbar tem `47px`, ao dar scroll ela ficaria com uns `30px`.

**Código da minha navbar pra exemplo:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-question"></i> About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: talvez esse pen te ajude, http://codepen.io/haykou/pen/FHKJg

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer um javascript para o evento de scroll.

Veja este exemplo, que coloca a navbar fixa no topo somente quando o scroll rolar para o topo da navbar:

```
$(function(){ //
   var navbarTop = $('#navbar').offset().top; // retorna a posicao

   $(window).scroll(function(){ // evento scroll
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (navbarTop < windowTop) {
          $('#navbar').addClass("navbar-fixed-top"); //adiciona a classe
          //$('#navbar').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0 }); ou altere o estilo conforme quiser
      } else {
          $('#navbar').removeClass("navbar-fixed-top"); //remove a classe
          //$('#navbar').css('position','static'); ou altere o estilo
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Neste exemplo a navbar tem o id="navbar".